# Check contents of javascript element with Cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

In our application we use IEPs (it's short for Incident Extended Property) where we store data in. In most cases we store one value in it like 'Yes' or 'Amsterdam' and we have to code to check these.

But we also have ComplexIEPS which store Javascript objects, so no JSON, an example:

```
[
    {
        "anotherField": true,
        "location": "xxx",
        "post": "XXX",
        "description": "Whatever",
        "transport": "1234"
    }
]
```

Is there a way to completely check this complexIEP? The code we use the simple IEPs:

```
cy.get('.className').contains('td', iepName)
    .parent()
    .children()
    .should(($children) => {
        const value = $children[1].innerHTML;
        expect(value).to.include(` ${iepValue}`);
    });
```

});

Comment: I know you said that your IEP is not a JSON object, but the example you've given is a JSON object. Are you absolutely positive that it is not a JSON object? After all, JSON is just a notation for JavaScript Objects.

Comment: Yes i'm absolutely sure that it is not a JSON object, i asked the developer himself.